# An auxiliary data structure required to improve performance of the application

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a requirement in one of my J2EE project, where I have to pre-process data  based on some business logic and formulate it into data structure (may be in memory database table) so I can use result by keeping look up into that data structure for primary key.

I am planning to refresh that data structure on server start, at periodic interval, and on user request.

Here what would be possible approve to design data structure?

Comment: This is called a *cache*. There are several caching libraries and APIs available in Java, for example [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/). It could also be as simple as a `HashMap`. What will work for you, depends on what your application needs exactly. If the data comes from a DB through for example Hibernate, then look into how to configure a second level cache for Hibernate.

Comment: Thank you Jesper, I am currently storing data in XML later I am planning to user database. In my current scenario which fits. Also if I use hashmap then how would I can access it accross application?

Comment: What a bout a in memory database like RADIS?

Comment: I found Ehcache implementation is most suitable here. In in memory could be one more to add it but it involves database support. Thanks.